# iCloud, keychain problems on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, icloud, keychain

My friend has an iPad. I have never used an iPad, but am trying to help her set things up better -- so it's clearly a case of the blind leading the blind.

We couldn't install Dropbox on the iPad because there's not enough storage. We think that's because there are too many photos stored on the iPad.  I tried to put some of them in iCloud and then download them on the Mac.  That step didn't work.  We got an error message about the keychain.  I'm nervous about doing anything to the keychain -- might that result in my friend losing stored passwords, or something else?

Please make your instructions detailed, clear and idiot-proof -- thank you!!

Comment: Can you try to plug the iPad to the MacBook with the USB cable, then launch Image Capture on the MacBook (located in applications) and then drag all the photos from the iPad onto a folder on the desktop? That should solve the free space on the iPad problem if the iCloud doesn't work. Then maybe upgrade iPad to iOS9?

Comment: Have you gone to `Settings > General > Usage` to see what's actually taking up the storage?

Comment: @IronCraftMan - Thanks for the edit.  "Storage" does sound right.

Comment: @fabriced - Well, I suppose that would require finding the special cable?  I'll see what I can do. /  I'm not sure I need to upgrade the iPad, that's not where I had the keychain problem.

Comment: @IronCraftMan - No.  There are a ton of photographs.  A *ton*.  I really think that's it.  But I will try your idea.  (I did check for music and videos, and found nothing there.)

Comment: "require finding the special cable" - it's the one you have to charge it with, every day...

Comment: @Tetsujin - Could you write an answer and include an image of the cable we should use?  Are we talking about connecting the iPad to the MacBook?  Once we do that, how do we do the transferring?

Comment: @fabriced - how do we check whether it's already running iOS9?  If it isn't, what are the advantages and disadvantages to upgrading?

Comment: @aparente001 well, if you are dealing with a bug, maybe it was solved in iOS9. Usually, if you are complaining about an old version of a OS, most people would tell you "that's why there's a new OS now". To check the OS, go into Settings -> General -> About -> Version

Comment: @fabrice - I see.  Well, there's no indication so far there's a bug in the gadget.

Comment: Wait, you have no OS version number in your settings? Can you share a screen cap of that screen if that's possible?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  We haven't checked yet.  /  Your advice sounds helpful.  I'll keep you posted here.